# How to solve "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running"

Tags: magento2, php, javascript

My magento 2.2.1 website backend prompts "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running." How to solve this kind of error? Does it have a big impact?

[image]

Comment: you need to run **php bin/magento indexer:reindex** command from your Magento project root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the below command from your command line.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

To resolve your indexer error.

If you want that to happen automatically then you will have to setup a cron job for that command to execute automatically.

Comment: If i don't handle it, will it affect the performance of your website? @Sourabh Kumar Sharma

Comment: If you run the required indexing manually when required, it won't affect the performance of your website.

Comment: thank you very much. I have cleaned up the index. @Sourabh Kumar Sharma

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Magento cron job so that reindexing will be handled by Magento. Or you need to run reindex command manually using command line.